# Imprimir datos de un JSON con PHP

Tags: php, php5

Quiero imprimir datos específicos de un JSON.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
  <?php
    $summoner = "ErickReplay";
    $key = "mikey";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://lan.api.riotgames.com/api/lol/LAN/v1.4/summoner/by-name/'.$summoner.'?api_key='.$key);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $obj = json_decode($result);

    print_r($obj);
    ?>
```

El mismo imprime lo siguiente:

```
stdClass Object ( [erickreplay] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 143048 [name] => ErickReplay [profileIconId] => 547 [revisionDate] => 1496449271000 [summonerLevel] => 30 ) )
```

Lo que quiero es imprimir solo el id lo cual sería 143048. He intentado de diferentes formas, pero no logro conseguirlo.

Comment: De las formas que has probado, ¿has usado alguna así? `$obj->erickreplay->id`

Comment: Si, ya he intentado de esa manera ($obj->erickreplay->id) y me aparecen los errores siguientes:

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ErickReplay in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\LOL\pruebas2.php on line 16  
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\LOL\pruebas2.php on line 16

Comment: Uhm... a ver, el error creo que es porque lo estás solicitando así: `$obj->ErickReplay->id` y no como he comentado al inicio `$obj->erickreplay->id`. La diferencia son las mayúsculas...

Comment: Estoy intentando de esa forma y obtengo los mismos errores.

Comment: ¿Y sigue reportando el mismo objeto? Si retorna el objeto tal cual lo pones en el `print_r` debería funcionar. El error es claro. ¿Que error te marca ahora? ¿Puede ser que lo estés usando en más de una línea del script?

Comment: Probé con echo $obj->ErickReplay->id y con print_r(echo $obj->ErickReplay->id;) y recibo los mismos errores.

Comment: Deberías incluir ese código como edición en la pregunta inicial. Lo que has puesto, tal cual, **sigue el mismo error** que venimos hablando. Al final del `script` tienes puesto `echo $obj->ErickReplay->id`. Cámbialo por `$obj->erickreplay->id`.

Comment: Tienes razón, no había probado correctamente. Ahora que reviso efectivamente era problema por las mayusculas. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegro. Si te sirvió, acuérdate de marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Y puntuarla si crees oportuno.

Comment: Ya marqué la respuesta como aceptada, pero al parecer no me permite puntuarla ya que tengo menos de 15 puntos de reputación.

Comment: Sin problemas, por aquí estamos para lo que necesites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma correcta es siguiendo el esquema jerárquico del objeto.

En el caso que muestras la respuesta del objeto.

```
stdClass Object ( [erickreplay] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 143048 //...
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ key 1                  ^^ key 2
```

Sería de la siguiente forma, manteniendo cada clave tal cual aparecen en orden de jerarquía.

```
echo $obj->erickreplay->id;
           ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^
           key 1        key 2
```

El error que indicas, `Undefined property: stdClass::$ErickReplay in...` lo que viene a decir es que la clave que estás buscando `$obj->ErickReplay` no está definida.

Comment: No sabes lo agradecido que estoy por tu excelente respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de ver esto, es que leas la respuesta como un array y no como un objeto.

```
$obj = json_decode($result, true);
```

y la forma de leer la respuesta seria:

```
$obj['erickreplay']['id'];
```